# Can't compile aws sdk for java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven

whenever I try to compile (mvn clean install) the aws sdk for java, I keep getting the following error for every library:

```
Failed to execute goal on project aws-java-sdk-textract: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-textract:jar:1.11.515-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.515-SNAPSHOT, com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-test-utils:jar:1.11.515-SNAPSHOT, com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.515-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.515-SNAPSHOT
```

any idea why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to do that in the first place?

Comment: To import the aws sdk library to my project.

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't) do that with Maven. Instead, you list this library as a dependency in your POM. (That said, there's a completely new v2 SDK for AWS out, and it's a lot better if it covers the functionality you need.)

Comment: I have three libraries listed in the POM.xml file. Textract, s3 and core. What should be the next step?

Comment: Make sure you've read documentation on how to add dependencies to your POM. If you are still having trouble, then post the POM and what's not working (e.g., not being able to resolve an import).

Answer (score 2):

The 1.11.515-SNAPSHOT version seems to not exist in mvn Repository

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-textract

Try to change the definition to:

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-textract -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-textract</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.513</version>
</dependency>
```

And see if all works.